# How do I control the shape of my spheres?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, spherification

I've been experimenting with reverse sphereification this week.  The results... well, the results remind me that even the professionals have to practice.

How do I control the tension of the alginate shell, so that it can maintain a round shape when bearing its own weight?  In other words, how do I get marbles instead of egg yolks?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is experiment with the height from which you drop them. Too low and there isn't enough time to form a sphere. Too high and you get too big a splat.